# Android app Share button not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I have create a new app and I want to show the SHARE button on the right side of the top bar. It used to work with previous apps but in this last one isn't displaying the share icon and I don't know why:

res/menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        />

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.share:
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if this is important, but I have this target on the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Any help is REALLY appreciated.

Comment: Do you have issue with only share action?

Comment: Yes, it's the only button I've added on the actionbar so far

Comment: Is the actionbar showing?

Comment: Are you using native Action bar or ActionBar sherlock?    If using ActionBarSherlock try getSupportMenuInflator() instead of getMenuInflator()

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes it is

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI native action bar, I used the same code on old apps and it worked, maybe is something on the new Android theme? don't know what else to try...

Comment: Check the difference between your working code theme and that one

Comment: Are you using support-v7 library?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes, support-v7

Comment: Did you try to use another drawable or to use that drawable in another working project?